# Cant call variadic function due to undefined reference

Tags: c++, opencl, variadic-templates

## !!! SOLUTION BELOW   !!!

---

I'm trying to extend the OpenCL wrapper `CL/cl2.hpp` so I can set any amount of `Kernel` arguments with just one call like this:

```cpp
setArgs(kernel, arg1, arg2, arg3,...);
```

To do that I've implemented these variadic templates for `setArgs`:

```cpp
// recursion end
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, uint i) {}

// actual recursive function
template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, uint i, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    kernel.setArg(i, arg);
    setArgs(kernel, i++, args...);
}

// split the argument list into head and tail
template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    setArgs(kernel, 0, arg, args...);
}

// I think this should be the first called function
template<typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    setArgs(kernel, 0, args...);
}
```

Calling it like `setArgs(kernel, bufferIn, bufferOut, (cl_double)3.14)` caused this error:

```cpp
undefined reference to void setArgs<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, double>(cl::Kernel const&, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, double)
```

I'm very sorry but I'm pretty new to C++11 variadic functions and I don't get why it doesn't work. I tried fiddling around but nothing worked. The code above is the most logical I can come up with.

PS: I know it's just syntax sugar but I it would reduce redundancy in my code a lot and it's propably good to understand variadic templates ;)

---

## !!! Solution!!!

### 1. Move templates to `.hpp`

Templates can only be implemented - that is declared AND defined in header files. So I needed to move the templates to the `.hpp` file and split the recursion end function definition to the `.cpp` file.

Thanks @NathanOliver for explaining.

### 2. Fix recursion abiguity

Consider the following method declarations:

```cpp
// A
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args)
// B
void setArgs(const cl::Kernel &kernel, uint i, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args)
```

Calling `setArgs(kernel, 42, argA, argB)` can match to both A and B. Thus the recursion expands to ever increasing size. This led to the following error message:

```
void setArgs(cl::Kernel&, ArgumentType, ArgumentTypes ...) [with ArgumentType = int; ArgumentTypes = {int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int...
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
```

Using `i` as the first parameter solved this ambiguity. Now I got the following code:

**kernel.hpp** (excerpt):

```cpp
void setArgs(uint i, cl::Kernel &kernel);

template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(uint i, cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    kernel.setArg(i, arg);
    setArgs(i + 1, kernel, args...);
}

template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    setArgs(0, kernel, arg, args...);
}

template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void setArgs(cl::Kernel &kernel, ArgumentType arg, ArgumentTypes... args) {
    setArgs(0, kernel, arg, args...);
}
```

**kernel.cpp** (excerpt):

```cpp
#include "kernel.hpp"

void setArgs(uint i, cl::Kernel &kernel) {}
```

---

### More elegant solution as class

**kernel.hpp** (excerpt):

```cpp
class Kernel : public cl::Kernel {
public:
    using cl::Kernel::Kernel;

    template<typename... ArgumentTypes>
    Kernel setArgs(ArgumentTypes ... args) {
        return _setArgs(args...);
    }

private :
    uint i = 0;

    template<typename ArgumentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
    Kernel _setArgs(ArgumentType arg, const ArgumentTypes ... args) {
        setArg(i, arg);
        i++;
        return _setArgs(args...);
    }

    Kernel _setArgs();
};
```

**kernel.cpp** (excerpt):

```cpp
#include "kernel.hpp"

Kernel Kernel::_setArgs() { return *this; }
```

**Calling the functions**:

```cpp
Kernel kernel = Kernel(device, kernelName)
    .setArgs(argIn, argOut)
    .setArgs(moreParams);
```

Comment: Is this code in a cpp file?

Comment: jup - do you need more for context?

Comment: *there is a header file that goes along with it

Comment: Nope.  You can see the dupe for the full details but the TL;DR is that all template code needs to be in a header file.

Comment: I actually have the same code in the cpp and in the hpp as well - just without the function bodies

Comment: The function bodies needs to be in the header file as well.  The way templates work in C++ requires that every cpp file you include the code into needs all of it, not just the declarations.

Comment: @OliverHabersetzer "_I actually have the same code in the cpp in the hpp as well - just without the function bodies_" Read the duplicate. The implementation itself ("function bodies") must be in a header file.

Comment: @OliverHabersetzer Not the reason for the problem (I agree with the above) but what caught my eye: If I see this right, `Kernel::setArg` is not a `const` method, so you shouldn't take the `kernel` parameter by `const` reference but just by reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think this should be a duplicate of the question you linked to since my code contains more problems. And it wasn't fixed by just moving it to another file. I edited the questions so more people could learn from it, explaining what I did to fix it and why.

Comment: All of that template code you have in kernal.cpp still needs to be moved to Kernal.hpp

Comment: Yeah mixed it up for the excerpt - fixed it now